# outputting data From Mysql to js/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

So Basically this is what i want to do , I want to take data from my database and then put that data on a page after the user logs in , however i am havinng problems understanding a way , So here's some sample code for clarity :

```
//user has logged in:
//fetched data from database to php file
$name = $result['name'] //result being the object after the queried row is fetched
```

now i want to add this name in lets say a div in my HTML

```
<div id="name"><!--$name comes here--></div>
```

So what is the way to do this using JS ? is AJAX the answer?

Comment: You do not need AJAX unless you plan on staying in the page that you originate the query from, without a reload.

Comment: you'd only want to use ajax if you dont' want to reload the page. if this html is being generated as a result of the user hitting a page or something why waste resources on an ajax call? why not just have php insert the value directly as the html's constructed? `echo "<div>$name</div>";`?

Comment: Thank you for that , so lets say i want to output data after user logs in from a login page to a profile page with reload then what is the way ?

Comment: Best to use a "Plan-B", if the user has JS disabled.

Comment: @MarcB i am trying to find a way to output data in an already made div using the id somehow?

Comment: He did `echo "<div>$name</div>";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes plan B is good but this is also for future learning :) this problem might come up sooner or later

Comment: so then its better to just echo a div?

Comment: because i have a template page with divs already created

Comment: `$.get('foo.php', function(data) { $('#name').html(data); }`, basically.

Comment: and i want to output values in them

Comment: I for one never load JS right off the bat ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have `$name` in the login.php file and the `div` is in profile.php. You can use session variables or ajax:

By php:
login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = $result['name'] 
?>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
<div id="name"><?php echo $_SESSION["name"]; ?></div>
```

By ajax:

getName.php

```
$name = $result['name'];
echo $name;
```

profile.js

```
$.get("getName.php", function(data, status){
    $("#name").append(data);
});
```